# How to get Access and Refresh Token while allowing google app by user

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

I created a google app and in Google app marketplace sdk api filled all the required details and added scopes what i required. And created a webapp in chrome developer dashboard and submitted the app for testing. While first time installing the app from marketplace it get permission from user for the scopes i added in the google app marketplace sdk api. After i click allow it will just install the app. Here how can i retrieve Accesstoken and refresh token or Authorization code while user clicks allow?

I manually get Auth code using this api call:

""[https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=CLIENTID &redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=email+profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&response_type=code&access_type=offline](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=CLIENTID%20&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&response_type=code&access_type=offline)""

In the redirected uri collects access and ref token using this api call:

```
String accessTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        String accessTokenUrlParameters = "client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&redirect_uri="
                + redirectUri + "&grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + code;
        String accessToken = null;
        String refreshToken = null;
        try {
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            hc.setURL(accessTokenUrl);
            hc.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(accessTokenUrlParameters.getBytes().length));
            hc.doPost("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

}

In this type i get both access and refresh tokens but while installing app for first time how do i get access token using that permissions and scopes.  The consent screen while installing app has url like this.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1234567890-1od573nk87eq712l7suam1hu9upa8tm2.apps.googleusercontent.com&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fapis.google.com&authuser=0&login_hint=abcdefghijk@gmail.com&response_type=token&redirect_uri=postmessage&hl=en&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile

but it doesnt have redirect uri and all. How to get access token while allowing this consent screen.

Comment: Check the [Refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) guide. It includes code snippets too. You can read more on refresh token on [Basic Steps and Scenarios](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#scenarios) for your google app auth flow.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it myself. Now i set access_type offline in the api call. it prompts the user like "Have offline access". How can i get offline access without prompt the user in consent screen?